# Is a part of an encrypted file easier to crack?

Tags: cryptography, gnupg

After encrypting a file (GPG with AES) and splitting it into chunks (split), is it easier to crack one of the parts compared to the complete file? (Maybe because it may loses some important bits.)

Comment: ...now, there are things that *can* make an attack easier -- for instance, if an attacker knows the first several blocks of plaintext, or has large amounts of context encrypted with the same key (though gpg uses a different symmetric key for each message), there are classes of attacks that can be opened up. But "easier" is a very relative thing -- in general, gpg is pretty good about following modern best practices, and being resilient enough for cases you're likely to see in practice.

Comment: "split it chunks( split ) is it easier to crack/hack one of the parts compared to complete file? (Maybe because it may lose some important bits.)" - if it was, attacker could split a file themselves so splitting does not make it easier/harder (as the same argument goes to merging the parts).

Comment: How could giving an attacker less information possibly make his job easier in any realistic set of circumstances?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz One could argue that in simple charcter-by-character cicphers such as Ceasars, the attacker can readily find the 0-character plaintext substring corresponging to any 0-character substring of the crypto text, but that's about all there is to say

Comment: If any kind of statistical analysis is useful in performing cryptanalysis, having more data will improve this.

Comment: no, it's actually harder for an attacker without having everything in front of him with most AES modes.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No. You still need to find the same length encryption key to decrypt the data into plaintext. Finding the key is the hard part, decrypting a whole or partial image is trivial once you have the key.

If you are using an encryption scheme where the file is encrypted and decrypted deterministicly based on the section that was last (de/en)ecrypted, it can be harder to reliably end up at the same plaintext as you would have gotten were you to perform the same decryption on the entire file, if the file is split *after* encryption. This is semi-relevant to CBC encryption schemes.You can recover plain-text blocks if your archive separates files into segments of two or more ciphertext blocks or longer. If you were to separate the entire ciphertext into segments of one cipher-block each, you would render any block missing both it's adjacent blocks as indecipherable.

If you are using a scheme that applies a different encryption key to each smaller segment, then you are increasing the number of keys needed to decrypt the entire message, but that is getting very implementation specific.

EDIT:

In regards to "losing important bits" - I assume you mean that if you were to split up the encrypted file and delete some of the segments (or store them elsewhere), you might be deleting parts of the file that ensure the security of the contents, such as a checksum or something.

The way that modern crypto works, your end result is two pieces of data - your encryption key, and the ciphertext. A good crypto algorithm won't have distinct "parts" in the ciphertext. It should be indistinguishable from white noise, ideally. Otherwise you are opening your ciphertext up to both detection and reverse engineering. So from a ciphertext, there are no specifically important bits to lose.

Comment: I don't understand your second paragraph.  If a plain-text is encrypted with a block cipher in CBC mode, to encrypt or decrypt block N, you need to have the cipher-text for block N-1.

Comment: @MartinBonner let me know if my edit makes more sense.

Comment: @Fistbeard : Yup, I think that helps.

Comment: i wanted to say that some important bits may stay another in another part because i'm just using split command to encrypted file, not using a proper encrypted splitting method.

Comment: It doesn't matter. No segments have any special meaning in a ciphertext. If they did it would (probably) significantly weaken the encryption.

Comment: What about if i re-encrpyt this parts once again with different algo? Does this add any better security or leaks anything?

Comment: You're making it more secure, but in such a way that it's not actually resolving any of the weak points in crypto. The strength of the encryption itself isn't what's going to get breached, so adding another layer of crypto doesn't help. Weak pass phrases, faulty implementations, etc. These are what you need to solve, not weakness of a well proven cryptographic suite.

Answer (score 4):

A great way to think about an "Does this make it easier to attack?"-question is to ask yourself "Can the attacker do it trivially?".

If splitting a file into chunks *were* actually making it easier to attack, then this would be the default procedure for every attacker. This brings us to an important observation: Encryption schemes do not have a fixed "strength". They are only as strong as the best currently-known attack is.

Let's take RSA for example: RSA relies on the fact that prime factorization is difficult. If someone were to develop an alogrithm which made it twice as easy to factor large primes, then RSA would become weaker.

Comment: Which is what the [NSA predicts](https://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2015/08/nsa_plans_for_a.html) will happen when quantum computers become usable in a not distant future.

Answer (score 3):

No. Splitting your file after encryption doesn't make attack easier. 
Indeed when you use an algorithm such as AES, the output (your encrypted file) is nearly equivalent to a set of random bits for someone who doesn't know the key used. So removing a part of this set will not help them in any case.

Comment: to be fair, it depends on the AES mode, see the encrypted tux bitmap for details...

Comment: @dandavis No. I think you make reference to ECB encryption mode but here we talk of splitting after encryption

Comment: yeah, if i had part of that image file, i could make out part of that image...

Answer (score 2):

For the sake of completeness, I'll point out that it is **possible** to split a file in a dangerous way.

How? Well, if the location of the splitting in any way depends on the key itself (e.g. maybe you split the key into 4-byte chunks and then split the file at the offsets given by every 4-byte value), then this can obviously leak the key.

How could this happen on accident?

1. You tell your 12-year-old child to split the file in a "fun" way, and he decides to do it based on the offsets given by the key.
2. You're **incredibly** bored **and** unaware of possible security concerns, and therefore try to be "creative" with the splitting, hence doing something similar.

Realistically, it wouldn't happen if you're paying any attention to what you're doing.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the Unix `split` utility mentioned in the question doesn't have an option to accept an encryption key, so OP is probably safe ;-)

Comment: @psmears: ah, I didn't realize it was referring to the `split` utility :P

Comment: Yep, it is split command from ubuntu terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly notice that when you encrypt a file using GPG with AES, what you are actually encrypting is already split into two parts since you are relying on a so-called "[hybrid encryption scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_cryptosystem)":

1. You will generate a random AES key which you can use to encrypt your data, that key is the "Data Encryption Key" (DEK), because symmetric ciphers such as AES are way faster than public key cryptography such as RSA.
2. The next step will use the GPG asymmetric algorithm (typically RSA) to encrypt that DEK with the public key of the recipient, which can then be called a "Key Encryption Key" (KEK)
3. The actual ciphertext in the end is composed of two parts: the encrypted DEK and the encrypted data.

Now, you can obviously split your ciphertext into the "RSA" part and the "AES" one without actually making it any harder for the attacker to break: she would still need to crack either the RSA part or the AES part, but that could make it harder for the attacker to actually obtain the part she's willing to crack (on an operational level.)

Now regarding the data itself, encrypting with AES means you're using a [mode of operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation) along with your symmetric cipher because plain AES can only encrypt 1 block of 128 bits. But the [OpenPGP standard](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4880) is defining its [very own variant](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4880#section-13.9) of the CFB mode, which means that you're relying on it when using GPG with AES.

Since the CFB variant used by OpenPGP actually features a "correct key check" within its two first blocks of encrypted data, it is sufficient to have the two first blocks of ciphertext to know whether one has found the correct key or not, however the decryption process of any block only relies on the AES DEK and the previous block of ciphertext.

So, from an *operational* point of view, splitting the data in such a way that no two concurrent blocks are transmitted together would probably increase the complexity of the attack, since the attacker would lack the IV even if she had the key, and so she would need to bruteforce both the IV of the blocks and the key...
However, from a *security theoretical* point of view, there is no significant increase or decrease of the security provided by AES and the CFB mode of operation by splitting the data into multiple chunks.

Notice that AES encryption is only considered secure as long as the key is a secret. (And the IV is not supposed to be a secret.)  This does not change when you perform any operation (not related to the key) on the ciphertext only, otherwise an attacker could simply do it herself.